# How can the Windows 7 sees the Windows 2012?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-server-2012, ping

I have installed a Windows 2012 Standard Server with Active Directory, DHCP and DNS server in Oracle Virtual Box. It has two Network Adapters (Ethernet and Ethernet 2). These Adapters are in same domain which named *konyvel.ek*.

And I have installed a Windows 7 client in VM too. It has an Ethernet. But it's Network Adapter say *Not identified network*. Therefore I can't ping to the Windows Server from the Windows Client. How can the Client sees the Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created a Network/vSwitch within Virtual box? you can use Host-only networking mode and attach server and win 7 to the same so that win 7 can send DHCP request to DHCP server. On Networking settings is correct in virtual box, windows 7 should gain an IP address from DHCP server.

Comment: I have opened the configurations in VM, and I have chosen the Host-only mode, but I can't push on the 'OK' button. The error message is 'Currently the Host-only Network Adapter there is not chosen!'.

Comment: To change a virtual machine's virtual network interface to "host only" mode:

either go to the "Network" page in the virtual machine's settings notebook in the graphical user interface and select "Host-only networking", or

on the command line, type VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nic<x> hostonly; see Section 8.8, “VBoxManage modifyvm” for details.

Comment: For host-only networking, like with internal networking, you may find the DHCP server useful that is built into VirtualBox. This can be enabled to then manage the IP addresses in the host-only network since otherwise you would need to configure all IP addresses statically.

In the VirtualBox graphical user interface, you can configure all these items in the global settings via "File" -> "Settings" -> "Network", which lists all host-only networks which are presently in use. Click on the network name and then on the "Edit" button to the right, and you can modify the adapter and DHCP settings.